# How can I convert this HashSHA256(("").Encode("utf-8")).HexDigest() to C#?

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, sha256

The next pseudo code is got from the [AWS documentation (section: Task 1, step 7)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/websocket-med.html):

```
payload_hash = HashSHA256(("").Encode("utf-8")).HexDigest()
```

It is used to calculate a payload of the GET-request.

For convenience, this pseudo code can be rewritten the next way:

```
utf8Bytes = ("").Encode("utf-8")
sha256Hash = HashSHA256(utf8Bytes)
payload_hash = sha256Hash.HexDigest()
```

How can I convert this pseudo code to `C#`?

Comment: So you need kind of hexdigest() function but in C#

Comment: @user3856437 Could you please add a link to the AWS documentation page where provided code can be found.

Comment: Here's the link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/websocket-med.html
It is under Task 1 number 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next sample is `C#` equivalent of the pseudo code you provided:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

...

public static void Demo()
{
    using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        string textToHash = "";
        byte[] bytesToHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToHash);            
        byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytesToHash);
        string hexDigest = ToHexStr(hash);

        Console.WriteLine(hexDigest);
    }
}

public static string ToHexStr(byte[] hash)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in hash)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    return hex.ToString();
}
```

This method produces the next result for an empty string:

```
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

This result matches example hashed value for en empty string from [AWS Documentation (step 6)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html).

Comment: I'll check this, but just a question. Why is this code: 

byte[] bytesToHash = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textToHash);

Comes first before

byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytesToHash);

Comment: @user3856437 **1.** Because firstly `UTF-8` encoded byte array of the text message must be calculated. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToHash);` is equivalent of the part `("").Encode("utf-8")`. **2.** And then `SHA256` hash of this byte array must be calculated. `byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytesToHash);` is equivalent of calling method `HashSHA256(...)`.

Comment: Sorry I thought the empty string is within the HashSHA256() then it is being encoded to UTF8.

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you very much! For my question above, I dunno why someone downvoted it!

Answer (score 0):

I converted the above answer to an extension method

```
public static class HashConverter
    {
        public static string ToHexString(this byte[] array)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(array.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in array)
            {
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            }
            return hex.ToString();
        }
    }
```